# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + 4(x^2 + y^2)}\,dx\, dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to solve the integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1 + 4(x^2 + y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$

I am using polar coordinates here to get :

$$ \int_{0} ^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sec \theta} \sqrt{(1 + 4r^2)} r \,dr \,d\theta +  \int_{\pi/4} ^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\operatorname{cosec}\theta} \sqrt{(1 + 4r^2)} r \,dr \,d\theta$$

After this integral becomes too complex to solve further . For eg : the first integral gives :

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac1{12}{((1 + 4\sec^2\theta)^{3/2} - 1)}\, d\theta$$

After this I am stuck how to proceed further, Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: While it's going to wind up the same regardless, I think, you should be able to integrate without the transformation to polar coordinates; take the inner integral as $\int\ \sqrt{(1+4y^2)+4x^2}\ dx$, evaluate this via the usual means, and then plug in the limits; you should get a complicated but manageable expression for the result that can then be integrated with respect to $y$.

Comment: Use the substitution $5\cosh^2t = 1+4\sec^2\theta$. For more details on why this works, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3335406/finding-solution-to-a-double-integral/3335517#3335517)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It boils down to integrate

$$I= \int_0^{\pi/4}(1+4\sec^2\theta)^{3/2}\,d\theta$$
Let $\sinh t= {\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}\tan\theta$ to proceed

\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}
\frac{50\cosh^4 t}{4+{5}\sinh^2t }dt
=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}
\frac{25(1+\cosh 2t)^2}{3+5\cosh2t}dt\\
 &=\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}
\left(5 \cosh2t + 7 + \frac{4}{3+5\cosh2t}\right)dt\\
 &= 6 + \frac72 \ln{5}+\cot^{-1}3
\end{align}